# Moving the calendar from left side of the page to the right hand side of the page

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

I have a calendar App, but is there a way to move the calendar and the calendar in view section, from the left hand side of the screen to the right hand side of the screen, as the red arrow mentioned on the below image?

[image]

**Edit::**

I move the `PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator` to be after the `pageStatusBar` Div, and then i added it inside a div with `float:right` as follow:-

```
<div id="pageStatusBar"></div>
<div style="float:right"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server" /></div>
```

But the calender have moved down instead of fit its position between the left quick lunch link and the date picker,as follow:-

[image]

So any idea how to fix this layout issue ?

**Edit 2**

I have added the following to my custom CSS :-

```
#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView
 {
        Width:50%;
}
```

but the calender will have wrong potion on IE , while it will be located correctly on firefox, but the "Calender in view" links will not be click-able on firefox, but still working well on IE. attached is a screen shot of how the calender looks on IE & Firefox after specifying the `width:50%`. any idea how to fix the position on IE and re-enable the "Calender in view" links on Firefox ??
[image]

**Edit3**
Firebug results are:-
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with doing this by modifying the master page. There is a place holder with the ID of PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator that should be what you need to move around. You could also do it with some JavaScript, but this would be more work than it's probably worth. Updating the masterpage would be easiest.

Comment: but what will be the best place to move the "PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" to ?

Comment: You'll need to figure that part out. In the masterpage, you will need to modify the HTML to move things around and put the calendar where you want it.

Comment: i have noted that the generated web page will have these two Divs <div id="DatePickerDiv" style="display:blok "></div>
<div class="ms-acal-apanel-outer"></div> . so if i modify these two div layout insdie my custom CSS , will it work ?

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want can be done via CSS. You can play around with it with your custom CSS, or use the dev toolbar to play around: http://davidlozzi.com/2013/05/08/a-non-developers-intro-to-the-developer-toolbar-element-inspection/

Comment: can you check my Edit to the original question. i manage to change the PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator location to be at right side of the screen. but the calender itself did not respond well to the change..

Comment: This will require some CSS/HTML changes to force the sizing of the calendar and/or its container.

Comment: thanks, can you check my second edit, i was able to position the calender on firefox ,, but it did not work on IE

Comment: This is the joy of web development. There are oddities and uniqueness between the browsers. You'll need to play with it some more to get it to work the same across all browsers. Is the default width for AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView 100%? If so, update the HTML to put the calendar into a container that fits, like a table or divs. this should play nicer across browsers.

Comment: Actually the AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView did not have a width define , but under it there is a class with width =100%. I have attached part of the firebug results for the calender , before defining the custom CSS..

Comment: i think the problem with the calender on firefox is when i add the PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator insdie a <div style="float:right"> . but not sure what is wrong with do so , and what other options i can have to move the PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator to the right???